# if condition not meet, leave blank python code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

how should we write the code that tell python to leave empty cell in dataframe when the condition is not meet?

I tries " " like excel but it does not work. I tried 'space' also not work either.

eg. np.where((df['Adj Close']> df['signal']), 1, 'what should be the sign here? ' )

Thanks in advance.

I am expecting the code to return blank cell in pandas dataframe when I run the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need empty numeric value use missing value `NaN`:

```
np.where(df['Adj Close']> df['signal'], 1, np.nan)
```

Comment: Thank you. it showed nan in column but it is blank when export to csv file.